# compare rows in 2d list and store the unique row having same elements in a row in another list

Tags: python, arrays, list, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D list from which I am trying to extract the unique rows example:

```
list = [['16', 'jun', 'jun', '18'],
        ['jun', '16', 'jun', '18'],
        ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
        ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
        ['sep', '17', 'mar', '18']]
```

should return

```
desired_list = [['16', 'jun', 'jun', '18'],
                ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
                ['sep', '17', 'mar', '18']]
```

explanation:

- So, if we compare row 1 with row 2 in list we see the items inside the two rows is same hence, I will take one of the row and store in desired_list
- row 3 and 4 in list are exactly same therefore, I'll store any one row in desired_list.
- row 5 is totally unique therefore, I'll add in desired_list.

My only target is to remove duplicate value rows(even if items inside rows have different order) and only store the unique rows.

```
print('LP:',lp, "\n")
l=[]
for i in range(len(lp)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(lp)):
        k=i
        print(set(lp[j]) == set(lp[k]), lp[j] not in l, lp[j], lp[k],l)
        if set(lp[j]) != set(lp[k]):
            if lp[j] not in l:
                l.append(lp[j])
print('\n', l)
```

I am only half successful in achieving this. Below I am attaching the screenshot of the output so far:
[image]

Comment: Do you want your new list to preserve the order of either the individual rows or the order within the rows? So for instance, in the example you give, would you care if the last row (starting with "sep") came first? And would you care if that row came up as ["mar", "sep". "18", "17"]?

Comment: So `['aug', 18, 'jun', 16]` is the same row as `['jun', 18, 'aug', 16]` (from what you said, it is. And f so, answers you got are correct, since the assume so). But just to be sure, because your only example of different order is one where month name and day of month have been swapped. So, still the same dates, just, order of dates are irrelevant, and way dates are specified ('jun', 18 vs 18, 'jun`) also are. While in my example, it is not just a date-format/date-order that change: it is not the same dates!

Comment: So, just to be sure that people who took your assumption "order does not matter" to face value are not unaware of an hidden constraint, that would say "dates, aka pairs of subsequent elements, must be the same".

Answer (score 0):

```
#input
in_list = [['16', 'jun', 'jun', '18'],
    ['jun', '16', 'jun', '18'],
    ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
    ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
    ['sep', '17', 'mar', '18']]

#output
np.array(in_list)[np.sort(np.unique(np.sort(in_list), axis=0, return_index=True)[1])].tolist()
```

Explanation:

- `np.sort` the rows of `in_list` in order to find the rows having the same information;
- take the index from `np.unique` to find the indices of unique (sorted) rows;
- `np.sort` the indices to hold the starting order in `in_list`;
- slice the list (after converting it in `np.array`) with the sorted indices to only retain the unique rows;
- converting the result in a list (`.tolist()`)

Answer (score 0):

Pure pythonic solution:

```py
res = []
for row in your_list:
    sorted_row = sorted(row)
    if sorted_row not in [sorted(x) for x in res]:
        res.append(row)

print(res)

>>> [['16', 'jun', 'jun', '18'],
     ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
     ['sep', '17', 'mar', '18']]
```

Comment: I'd say have two different lists, res and sorted_res where you append row to res and sorted_row to sorted_res so that in the if statement you just check the sorted_res list instead of sorting every row in res again for every iteration of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code:

```
lp = [['16', 'jun', 'jun', '18'],
        ['jun', '16', 'jun', '18'],
        ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
        ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
        ['sep', '17', 'mar', '18']]


print('LP:',lp, "\n")
l=[]
count = 0
for i in lp:
    for j in lp[count+1:]:
        if set(j) != set(i):
            if i not in l:
                l.append(i)
    count += 1
print(l)
```

I would advise against using this strategy as your algorithm is O(n^2) because it needs to run through every element in your list for every element in your list aka x*x times. I would use this code:

```
def remove_values_from_list(the_list, val):
    
    return [value for value in the_list if sorted(value) != sorted(val)]

lp = [['16', 'jun', 'jun', '18'],
        ['jun', '16', 'jun', '18'],
        ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
        ['aug', '16', 'jun', '18'],
        ['sep', '17', 'mar', '18']]


print('LP:',lp, "\n")
l=[]
count = 0
oof = 5
result_list = []
while True:
    
    if len(lp) == 1:
        break

    element = lp[1]
    
    lp = [element] + remove_values_from_list(lp[count+1:], element)
    result_list.append(element)
    

    
print("Result")
print(result_list)
```

This code is a lot more efficient because it removes every instance of the current element in the rest of the list so it does not need to compare those copies anymore in future cases. Also that code also works if there are duplicate elements in your lists. When using set() you can not have duplicate elements because of the way sets work internally in python.

Here is a simple script to test the speed increase: (it also checks the validity of the solutions by doing a manual O(n^2) check, but that is of course not part of the main program)

```
import random
import colorama
from colorama import Fore, Style
import time


def generate_list_of_1000_integers(n_min, n_max, len):
    return [random.randint(n_min, n_max) for _ in range(len)]

def remove_values_from_list(the_list, val):
    #return [value for value in the_list if set(value) != set(val)]
    return [value for value in the_list if sorted(value) != sorted(val)]
def solution(lp):
    l=[]
    count = 0
    for i in lp:
        for j in lp[count+1:]:
            if set(j) != set(i):
                if i not in l:
                    l.append(i)
        count += 1
    return l

def anothersolution(lp):
    
    count = 0
    result_list = []
    while True:
        
        if len(lp) == 1:
            break

        
        element = lp[1]
        
        lp = [element] + remove_values_from_list(lp[count+1:], element)
        result_list.append(element)
        
    return result_list

if __name__=="__main__":
    where_to_pick_from = [generate_list_of_1000_integers(0,100,10) for _ in range(100)]

    complete_list = []

    how_many = int(2000)

    for _ in range(how_many):
        list_thing = random.choice(where_to_pick_from)
        random.shuffle(list_thing)
        complete_list.append(list_thing)


    print(complete_list)
    start = time.time()
    sol = solution(complete_list)
    print("First solution took "+str(time.time() - start)+str(" seconds."))
    start = time.time()
    sol2 = anothersolution(complete_list)
    print("Second solution took "+str(time.time() - start)+str(" seconds."))


    


    for j in range(len(sol)):
        for i in range(len(sol)):
            if set(sol[i]) == set(sol[j]) and j != i:
                print(Fore.RED+"[-] Solution 1 invalid.")
                exit(-1)
    for j in range(len(sol2)):
        for i in range(len(sol2)):
            if set(sol2[i]) == set(sol2[j]) and j != i:
                print(Fore.RED+"[-] Solution 2 invalid.")
                exit(-1)

    print(Fore.BLUE+str("[+] Solutions valid!"))
```

Edit: I am also a beginner programmer myself so constructive criticism is welcome.